# Why can't @babel/node find a local file for an import?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, babel-node

I'm working on a small project to get more familiar with setting up a Node project and running it. I'd like to write it in ES6 and run it through an NPM script, so I installed the following libraries:

```
"@babel/cli": "7.2.3",
"@babel/core": "7.3.3",
"@babel/node": "7.2.2",
"@babel/preset-env": "7.3.1"
```

In the root of my project, I have an index.js entry point, and have created the following script in my package.json: `"order": "babel-node index"`
When I do `npm run order` in the console, though, I get the following error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module './src/read-file'
```

The first line in my index.js is: `import { readFile } from './src/read-file';`
This is my .babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

What am I missing to make it work?

Comment: Your file architecture is missing. In any case, it is most likely your path to the read-file that is wrong.

Comment: It was! I had just posted this and started looking again when I realized that "./src/read-file" points to a directory, with the file being inside that. The import statements needs to be from "./src/read-file/read-file"